# Accessing object[x] index in C# gives cast object to object[] error

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have a simple piece of code:

```
object[] result = this.getData("baseLogin", args);
if (result.Count() > 0)
   return result[0];
```

Method `getData` returns object[] ofcourse.
Everything looks fine but `result[0]` gives following error:

> > Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'object[]'.
> >     An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Why does it treat object[] as object and wants to convert it to object[]?

Comment: Can you post the code for `getData()` please?

Comment: You will have to show a little bit more of your code, and what the return type is. Also, what is the type of result[0]

Comment: `result[0]` is `object` not `object[]`

Comment: Very basic programming.. when you got array of objects, each item is an object by itself, not array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by any chance `getData` is returning array of arrays, meaning each item in the result array is array by itself, the compiler can't know that... you have to convert it explicitly like this:

```
if (result.Count() > 0)
   return (object[])result[0];
```

This will give run time error in case the item is something else.

Comment: Thats solves the problem. I also tried casting but i did it using 'as' keyword. Easiest things are so hard sometimes! Thanks!

Comment: Cheers! Please add the information to your question (that each item is array by itself and that you tried to cast and failed) as it explains things better.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that the return type of your method is `object[]` and not `object`:

```
object[] DoSomething()
{
    object[] result = this.getData("baseLogin", args);
    if (result.Count() > 0)
       return result[0];  // <- This line returns an object. But the return type
                          // of the method is object[]
}
```

It depends on what you really need.
If you really only want to return the first object, change your methods return type to `object`. If - for some reason - you need to return an `object[]` with only the first element in it, change the return statement to this: `return new object[] { result[0] };`.